# Find the row with the highest value in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

According to the schema, the `Orders` table has the following columns:

`OrderId integer, CustomerId integer, RetailerId integer, ProductId integer, Count integer`

I'm trying to figure out what product has the highest number of orders for each retailer.

So, to sum up all the orders per product, I have the following query:

```
SELECT RetailerId, ProductId, SUM(Count) AS ProductTotal
FROM Orders
GROUP BY RetailerId, ProductId
ORDER BY RetailerId, ProductTotal DESC;
```

This gives an output like this:

```
RETAILERID  PRODUCTID PRODUCTTOTAL
---------- ---------- ------------
         1          5          115
         1         10           45
         1          1           15
         1          4            2
         1          8            1
         2          9           12
         2         11           10
         2          7            1
         3          3            3
         4          2            1
         5         11            1
```

Now, all I want to do is find the product with the highest number of orders per retailer. Right now, it shows all the products; I want only one.

I have tried way too many things. Following is one particularly abhorrent example:

```
SELECT O.RetailerId, O.ProductId, O.ProductTotal
FROM (
  SELECT Orders.ProductId, MAX(ProductTotal) AS MaxProductTotal
  FROM (
    SELECT Orders.ProductId AS PID, SUM(Orders.Count) AS ProductTotal
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY Orders.ProductId
  ) AS O INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.ProductId = PID
  GROUP BY Orders.ProductId
) AS X INNER JOIN O ON O.RetailerId = X.RetailerId AND O.ProductTotal = X.MaxProductTotal;
```

The solution to this is probably the simplest thing ever, but I just can't right now. So, I'd like some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the maximum total per customer with a window function:

```
SELECT RetailerId, ProductId, ProductTotal
FROM
(
  SELECT
    RetailerId, ProductId, SUM(Count) AS ProductTotal,
    MAX(SUM(Count)) OVER (PARTITION BY RetailerId) AS MaxProductTotal
  FROM Orders
  GROUP BY RetailerId, ProductId
)
WHERE ProductTotal = MaxProductTotal
ORDER BY RetailerId;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using window function `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by RetailerId order by ProductTotal desc) as rn from
(
SELECT RetailerId, ProductId, SUM(Count) AS ProductTotal
FROM Orders
GROUP BY RetailerId, ProductId
)A
)X where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `row_number()` with cte

```
with cte as
(
   SELECT o.RetailerId,o.ProductId AS PID, SUM(o.Count) AS ProductTotal
    FROM Orders o
    GROUP BY o.ProductId,o.RetailerId
), cte2 as
(
select RetailerId,PID,ProductTotal, 
row_number() over(partition by RetailerId order by ProductTotal desc) as rn
from cte
) select RetailerId,PID,ProductTotal from cte2 where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using rank?

Try this query

```
select OrderC, retailer_id,product_id from ( select sum(count_order) as OrderC,retailer_id,product_id,row_number() over(order by OrderC desc) as RN from order_t  group  by retailer_id,product_id) as d where RN=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version without sub-query using [FIRST](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641)/LAST:

```
WITH t(RETAILERID, PRODUCTID, PRODUCTTOTAL) AS (    
    SELECT 1,  5,  115 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 10,   45 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,  1,   15 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,  4,    2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,  8,    1 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,  9,   12 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 11,   10 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,  7,    1 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,  3,    3 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,  2,    1 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,11,    1 FROM dual)
SELECT 
   RETAILERID, 
   MAX(PRODUCTID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY PRODUCTTOTAL) AS PRODUCTID, 
   MAX(PRODUCTTOTAL)
FROM t
GROUP BY RETAILERID;


+--------------------------------------+
|RETAILERID|PRODUCTID|MAX(PRODUCTTOTAL)|
+--------------------------------------+
|1         |5        |115              |
|2         |9        |12               |
|3         |3        |3                |
|4         |2        |1                |
|5         |11       |1                |
+--------------------------------------+
```